# Bamboo logs output order issue

Tags: python, maven, subprocess, bamboo

I've written a python script and integrated it on bamboo. I have a maven command in my script and the weird thing is when I run my script on bamboo, the output order of results in logs is wrong. Is there something wrong with my script?

**below is result when I was running my script on a unix server. The order is correct**

Group Name:                  vmEPP

Artifact Name:               vmEPP

Name:                        vmEPP

Artifact Version:            2014.02.0.2

Artifact:                    vmEPP-2014.02.0.2.jar

manifestEntries:             Found

Version-2014.02.0.2          NOT Found in Maven

Validation Check:            Succeeded

[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Building vmEPP 2014.02.0.2

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

**But when I was running it on bamboo, logs showed as below. It displayed maven command result first and then printed out validation information:**

[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 30.994s

[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 26 16:18:20 PDT 2014

[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/108M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Group Name:                  vmEPP

Artifact Name:               vmEPP

Name:                        vmEPP

Artifact Version:            2014.02.0.2

Artifact:                    vmEPP-2014.02.0.2.jar

manifestEntries:             Found

Version-2014.02.0.2          NOT Found in Maven

Validation Check:            Succeeded

I'am new to bamboo and have no idea about it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen this answer? [answers.atlassian](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/31595/bamboo-build-log-not-in-sync)

Essentially, it depends what stream is being logged to.  stdout is buffered while stderr is logged immediately.

Comment: Thank your very much. That answer is helpful!